# jQuery if li has a ul child inside it make it the first list item to show

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a multiple level navigation menu. The list items are organized according to its HTML hierarchy. I want jquery to find the `li` which has a child `ul` inside it and show that list item as the **first item** inside the `ul.list1`.

Here is the sample HTML:

```
<ul class="list1">
  <li><a href="#">List item 1</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">List item 2</a></li>
  <li class="slicknav_parent"><a href="#">List item 3</a>
    <ul>
       <li><a href="#">Child Item 1</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">Child Item 2</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">Child Item 3</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">Child Item 4</a></li>
   </ul>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">List item 4</a></li>
</ul>
```

In the above I want the **List item 3** to be the first list item to show. How can this be achieved using *jQuery*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this way:

```
$("li").find("ul").each(function () {
    var theLI = $(this).closest("li"); // This is the `li`, which we are interested in.
    theLI.prependTo(theLI.closest("ul"));
});
```

The `prependTo()` function will prepend the element as the first child.

You also have an error in your code. You forgot to close the `"list1"`.

**Snippet**

```js
$(function () {
  $("li").find("ul").each(function () {
    var theLI = $(this).closest("li"); // This is the `li`, which we are interested in.
    theLI.prependTo(theLI.closest("ul"));
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="list1">
  <li><a href="#">List item 1</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">List item 2</a></li>
  <li class="slicknav_parent"><a href="#">List item 3</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Child Item 1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Child Item 2</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Child Item 3</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Child Item 4</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">List item 4</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: thanks. Let me try it and if it works I shall accept this.

Answer (score 3):

```
$( "ul.list1 li" ).has( "ul" ).prependTo("ul.list1");
```